# center alignment if first two column in centers and text alignment in vertically middle latex

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am facing an alignment problem in the first three columns. I want to align in the center of the column and also center in a row. I used the excel plugin to generate a latex table but it's quite complicated. Please suggest to me some easy code in which I will complete the first complete row with a column and then I will move on to another one. I also want to a little gap between rows.

**Code**

```
    \begin{table*}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
    \begin{tabular}{p{8.855em}rp{13.785em}p{25.5em}c}
    \toprule
    \toprule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{XXXXXX}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{XXXX }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{XXXXXXX}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{MXXXXXX}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\#XXXXXX}} \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & \multicolumn{1}{c}{[17]} & XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 237 \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & \multicolumn{1}{c}{[18]} & XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  & 42 \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx & \multicolumn{1}{c}{[19]} & IXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,\newline{}2018 & XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 34 \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & \multicolumn{1}{c}{[20]} & JXXXXXXXXXXXXX & FXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 44 \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .929,  .929,  .929} \textbf{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX} &       & \textbf{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxx} & \textbf{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX} & \textbf{-} \\
    \bottomrule
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does "align in the center of the column and also center in a row" refer to vertically and horizontally centered contents? What does "complete the first complete row with a column" refer to? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I am a new one. vertically and horizontally centered contents "Yes". I mean that "complete the first complete row with a column" any easy implementation in which i will handle all things easily. Easy to understand.

Comment: Since I am not sure if I understand the required output corretly: Is this the layout you want to achieve?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8LQB.png

Comment: Yes of course 100%

Comment: I also want light gray colour in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
Text in tables is on demand of OP replaced by dummy text generated by package `lipsum`.

This request I also exploit for introducing some small improvements (according to my taste) in table design:

- For table is now used `tabularx` environment. Using it the width of table is equal to text width.
- Since package `cellspace` overwrite automatic split of `X` column cells contents, in preamble is added command `\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}`

You may liked redesigned table. In this I follow to the most suggestion given in nice guide how to set [beautiful tables](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/). At this is table code is much shorter at least:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{boldline}% part of shipunov bundle
\usepackage{cellspace, makecell, tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\bfseries}

\renewcommand\theadgape{\bfseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[htbp]
    \centering
\caption{\lipsum[66]}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
                >{\centering\columncolor{gray!30}} S{X}
                >{\columncolor{gray!30}}r
                >{\centering\columncolor{gray!30}} S{X}
                >{\RaggedRight\columncolor{gray!30}}p{21em}
                >{\columncolor{gray!30}}c
                            }
    \hlineB{2}
\thead{text}
    &   \thead{text}
        &   \thead{text}
            &   \thead{text text}
                &   \thead{text}     \\
    \hlineB{1.5}
text text text text
    &   [17]
        &   \lipsum[1][1]
            &   \lipsum[1][2-3]
                &   237                 \\
\lipsum[1][4]
    &   [18]
        & \lipsum[1][5]
            &   \lipsum[1][6]
                &   42                  \\
\textbf{\lipsum[2][2]}
    &   &   \textbf{text text}
            &   \textbf{\lipsum[2][4]}
                &   \textbf{-}          \\
    \hlineB{2}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have also vertical centered text in table, than you need to replace column specifier `p{...}` with `m{...}` and add command `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` to document preamble (if you like to have all tables designed in such a way) or in table preamble (before `\begin{tabularx}` . Result is then:

[image]

Comment: I want to increase the width of the table and and add double line in top and bottom row. If you see in reference column there is some white portion. Why?

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to make one request . Is it possible for you to remove the text inside table and mention with some another rough text because this is my thesis table. Please. I will also do it. Its my mistake. Please accept my apologize

Comment: @KhawarIslam, done. I also add some small changes to table design.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @KhawarIslam, you are welcome, however, here thankfulness is usual expressed by upvoting of unswer(s) :-)

Comment: Done. I am new one